# SCVMM 2012 SP1 - "Isolate using Hyper-V network virtualization" grayed out

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines, scvmm, hyper-v-server-2012

I want to create a VM Network which is isolated. But the option "Isolate using Hyper-V network virtualization" is grayed out. Why?

Comment: Did you create the logical network first and then create the VM network?  - Harold Wong

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to tick "Allow virtual machines to use this network" in the logical network settings.